# Normal Map Seam Problem

Tags: normals, texture-baking

When i add normal map it creates seam in the mesh how can i fix this ?

I generate normal map from the diffuse with some maps generator program.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your mirror modifier on? Try Applying it, then select whole mesh, then press M - > by distance. Also, if your seam is on the middle it will probably always be seen. Try to avoid places for seam where you can see it. Instead, put it "under" that monster - around legs, around neck and so on

Comment: the seam completely split the mesh in half there is seam above and below can you dowload the file and look of it please ?

Comment: i try the mirror modifier and m-by distance result is same

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the normal *Image Texure* to *Non-Color*:

[image]

Other than that, check your UV Editor, the UV maps of the right and left sides of your objects are overlapping, it makes the texture mirror on the surface of your object.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but the result is not good as i want, also i need to export as fbx and reimport to unreal engine 4 so non-color method not work for unreal engine 4 i suppose ?

Comment: I'm talking about the Image Texture that is plugged into the Normal Map node, it improves the result. Other than that, check your UV Editor, the UV maps of the right and left sides of your objects are overlapping, that's why there's a mirror effect on the surface of your object

Comment: ohh okay thanks